# What's the difference between functor and lambda when used for constructing std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I'm testing a code from the book *C++ Concurrency in Action*. Basically, it uses multi-thread to implement the same function as `std::accumulate`. As the following shows, I tried to use lambda in place of functor, **but my code gave wrong results**.
 The variable `is_from_book` can be toggled to test the two ways.

```
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace para {

template<typename Iter, typename Value>
struct AccumulateBlock
{
    void operator ()(Iter first, Iter last, Value& result)
    {
        result = std::accumulate(first, last, result);
    }
};

template<typename Iter, typename Value>
Value parallel_accumulate(Iter first, Iter last, Value init_val)
{
    using std::size_t;
    size_t length = std::distance(first, last);
    if(length == 0) return init_val;    // trivial case

    size_t min_per_thread = 25;
    size_t max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;
    size_t hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    size_t num_threads = std::min((hardware_threads!=0 ? hardware_threads : 2), max_threads);
    size_t block_size = length/num_threads;
    std::vector<Value> results(num_threads);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads{num_threads - 1};

    Iter block_start = first;
    for(unsigned long idx=0; idx!=(num_threads-1);  ++idx )
    {
        Iter block_end = block_start;
        std::advance(block_end, block_size);

        if(bool is_from_book = false)   //code from the book that uses functor
        {
            threads[idx] = std::thread{
                    para::AccumulateBlock<Iter, Value>{},
                    block_start,
                    block_end,
                    std::ref(results[idx])
            };
        }
        else    //my code that tries to use lambda instead of functor
        {
            threads[idx] = std::thread{
                [&]{
                    results[idx] = std::accumulate(block_start, block_end, results[idx]);
                }
            };
        }

        block_start = block_end;
    }

    para::AccumulateBlock<Iter, Value>{}(block_start, last, results[num_threads-1]);

    for(auto& t : threads)  t.join();
    return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init_val);
}
}//namespace

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10000,1);
    auto sum = para::parallel_accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is what's the problem? Am I doing right? Any difference between the two ways? How to fix it?Thx.

Comment: When you say that your code "is not working", what do you mean by it? Do you have build errors (what are they then)? Do you have runtime errors (e.g. crashing)? Is the result not what you expect (what *did* you expect, and what's the actual result)? Please elaborate.

Comment: That usage of std::thread doesn't look exception safe?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I expected `10000`, but my code gave wrong result..And every time it gave different results.

Comment: @paulm: It depends what you mean by "safe". An exception at the wrong point here will terminate the program, which might or might not be what you want, but is certainly better than UB.

Comment: I mean std::thread would be in a RAII wrapper else an exception means that they won't get join()'d?

Comment: @paulm: Yes, although it's not quite traditional RAII. The destructor will terminate the program if you haven't joined or detached the thread. So an exception here is "safe" in the sense of well-defined behaviour; but not "safe" if safety requires the program to continue afterwards.

Comment: I think the most common use case is that the application shouldn't abruptly die, so for me this isn't "safe"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're capturing everything by reference, so `idx`, `block_start` and `block_end` are shifting under the thread's feet, causing all manner of undefined behaviour.

Capture `results` by reference - or, safer still, just the array element the thread needs - and the others by value:

```
Value & result = results[idx];
threads[idx] = std::thread{
    [&result,block_start,block_end]{   // or [=,&result] if you like brevity
        result = std::accumulate(block_start, block_end, result);
    }
};
```

Comment: Works now. I tried `[&result,=]` as well, not working, but `[=, &result]`works.Thx man~

Comment: @YueWang: That's right, I'd forgotten that the capture default has to come first. Corrected now.